# error with plasma display: "org.kde.plasma.private.kicker" is not installed

Tags: kubuntu, display, kde, crash, plasma

I was trying to fix a sound problem in kubuntu, and when I restarted my pc, my desktop disappear, and my toolbar and menu are sending errors. 
There is a message that says:
Error al cargar archivo QML: file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.kickoff/contents/ui/Kickoff.qml:31:1: module "org.kde.plasma.private.kicker" is not installed
Can someone help me? thanks a lot for your time.
[desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLbKx.png)

Answer (score 1):

ok,I've solved it using:
sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-desktop;
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop;